# How to handle a pop up with only <x> button using cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

[image]How to close the pop up with only  in the pop up using cypress?

Comment: Show us some code for the popup - there is likely an element with a unique id or class name we can use to select and click on.

Comment: i already upload the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the `button` and choose "Copy Selector" and you can use the class or the `data-dismiss` to select the element and `.click` on it with Cypress.